# How to check if the server is connected in python asyncore module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, asyncsocket, asyncore

I want to create a client that automatically reconnects if it loses the connection to the server. Therefore I ofcourse need to know if the server is connected. I want to use the asyncore module.
My initial geuss would be to check

> dispatcher.connected

However, since the socket is non-blocking, there is always a EWOULDBLOCK error returned. Therefore before every connect I have to set the socket to non-blocking, try to connect and set it to blocking again.

Am I missing something here? Since the default code always returns an error( on windows atleast) the base implementation always says non-connected whilest in fact, it is connected.

Comment: There is no TCP APi that knows wheter a socket is still connected. You have to do some I/O to discover that. This is by design,

Comment: Yes, but a socket can tell if a connectie was succesfull, however with async the status is always unsuccessfull, regardless of the actual success status

Comment: interesting. Some code would be helpful to reproduce the error. However, on connection, what will be the status of `self.is_connected`? if a connectie was successful, `is_connected` should be `true`. If otherwise, there really is no connection.

Comment: Where are you checking for connection status? Its important to note that once `asyncore.loop()` is called, the control is handed over to event loop that runds. Any code that runs after will be only executed after event loop has been shut down.